# Running a server-side executable

Tags: windows-xp, web-server, executable

I'm making a prototype webserver that needs to be able to run an executable on the server side.  How do I get this to work?  Do I need to set some permissions on the executable/directory?  I'm stuck building this on a Windows XP machine with IIS 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use [Windows PowerShell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx). It has an XP version which can be used to script what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could use classic ASP, and ["shell" out to run the executable](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-execute-a-dos-command/batch-file/exe-from-asp.html).

(There are a myriad better ways, but ASP is built into IIS and may do what you want.)